# URL redirect using .htaccess gives 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to redirect anyone surfing to http://forum.student.khleuven.be to http:// forum.kringraad.be. Both URL's redirect to the same directory, basically. I tried the following using .htaccess:

```
Redirect permanent http://forum.student.khleuven.be/ http://forum.kringraad.be/
```

and also the following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^forum\.student\.khleuven\.be$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://forum.kringraad.be/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Both give me a 500 Internal Server Error. I double checked that mod_rewrite is enabled, and it is. I'm pretty clueless, to be honest :) Anyone know what to do?

Comment: `500` errors always leave a verbose error message in `error.log`. Can you post that?

Comment: You should tag this with the web server software you're using...

Comment: I haven't got access to the server logs, I'm afraid. But I can tell you I'm using apache (and I've added it as a tag to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the solution was this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^forum.student.khleuven.be$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://forum.kringraad.be/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

I just had to remove the escapes. I don't know why I don't have to escape those dots, but it works perfectly like this.